# Airflow PythonOperator throws Negsignal.SIGKILL/SIGABRT on Mac

Tags: python, airflow, boto3

I've PythonOperator which uses boto3 to connect to AWS and download files from S3. My Airflow cluster is setup locally. When I run DAG in `DebugExecutor` mode everything seems to work correctly but in `LocalExecutor` it's throwing following error. Is there a way to debug this as logs are not much useful.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-06-11 13:48:12,977] {taskinstance.py:867} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-06-11 13:48:12,977] {taskinstance.py:868} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-06-11 13:48:12,997] {taskinstance.py:887} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): download_from_s3> on 2016-11-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2021-06-11 13:48:13,000] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 90339 to run task
[2021-06-11 13:48:13,102] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: download_dags.download_from_s3 2016-11-01T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> 
[2021-06-11 13:48:13,137] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-06-11 13:48:13,137] {sync_dag.py:48} INFO - Starting download 
[2021-06-11 13:48:22,924] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-06-11 13:48:22,923] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,212] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: download_dags.download_from_s3 2016-11-01T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,247] {taskinstance.py:655} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: download_dags.download_from_s3 2016-11-01T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,247] {taskinstance.py:866} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,247] {taskinstance.py:867} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 2
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,247] {taskinstance.py:868} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,253] {taskinstance.py:887} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): download_from_s3> on 2016-11-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,256] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 92685 to run task
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,336] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: download_dags.download_from_s3 2016-11-01T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> 
[2021-06-11 13:52:29,370] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-06-11 13:52:29,369] {sync_dag.py:50} INFO - Starting download 
[2021-06-11 13:52:39,191] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-06-11 13:52:39,190] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGABRT
```

```
def download_directory_from_s3(bucket_name, remote_directory_name, path_to_download=None):
    try:
        logging.info("Starting download ")
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3',
                                     aws_access_key_id=os.getenv("ACCESS_KEY"),
                                     aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv("SECRET_KEY"))

        bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
        logging.info("Authentication success")

        for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=remote_directory_name):
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(path_to_download, obj.key))):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(path_to_download, obj.key)))
            bucket.download_file(obj.key, os.path.join(path_to_download, obj.key))
    except Exception as es:
        logging.exception("Exception :", str(es))
    return "DownloadSuccess"

with DAG(dag_id='download_dags', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@once') as dag:
     download_kwargs = {
            'bucket_name': 'bucket_name',
            'remote_directory_name': 'path',
            'path_to_download': 'local_path'
        }
        step1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='download_from_s3',
            python_callable=download_directory_from_s3,
            op_kwargs=download_kwargs

        )
```

Comment: Why dont you use S3Hook to download the file?

Comment: Tried that too, but getting same error. I thought directly using boto library I can control logging or code flow to see if I can get any more info.

Comment: Please show the full log

Comment: Updated log file but it just contains retry attempts with same logs

Comment: I assume you run it on MacOS? see if setting `$ export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` solve the issue https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10435#issuecomment-756083946

Comment: Did it work or not?

Comment: Yes, I was indeed on Mac and `export` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running it on MacOS. Set:

```
$ export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

should fix the issue ([reference](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10435#issuecomment-756083946)).